# Is it possible to display the optionsText while storing the optionsValue in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is my current code

```js
var model = function() {
    this.nameSomething = ko.observable('');
    this.nameId = ko.observable(0);
};

var vm = (function() {
var myList = [{ id: 1, type: 'foo1'}, { id: 2, type: 'foo2' }, { id: 3, type: 'foo3' }],
    selectedModel = ko.observable(model);
    
    return {
        myList: myList,
        selectedModel: selectedModel
    };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: selectedModel">
    <select data-bind="options: $root.myList,
                       optionsText: 'type',
                       optionsValue: 'type',
                       value: nameSomething"></select><br />
    Display this: <span data-bind="text: nameSomething"><br />
    Store this: <span data-bind="text: nameId"><br /> <!-- not displaying anything -->
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedModel, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Is it possible to store the `optionsValue` in the `nameId` and the `optionsText` to `nameSomething` upon loading/changing the option?

My reason for this is I need to display the selected `optionsText` in the UI and store in the database the `optionsValue`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Any good pointers for new knockout users are welcome as well.

**EDIT**

Included a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uymuj2hk/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the entire object as the "selected value". You can then easily separate what you "show" and what you "store".

```js
var defaultItem =  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'foo1',
};

var vm = (function() {
var myList = [{ id: 1, type: 'foo1'}, { id: 2, type: 'foo2' }, { id: 3, type: 'foo3' }],
    selectedModel = ko.observable(defaultItem);
    
    return {
        myList: myList,
        selectedModel: selectedModel
    };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: myList,
                       optionsText: 'type',
                       value: selectedModel"></select><br />
    <div data-bind="with: selectedModel">
        <span>Display this: </span><span data-bind="text: type"></span><br />
        <span>Store this: </span><span data-bind="text: id"></span><br />
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedModel, null, 2)"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution. Wasn't aware of this!!

Comment: I see. I thought the value of the "value" is same as the "optionsValue". Is it?

Comment: `optionsValue` is an optional key/function that you can use to determine what your "selected value" should be when that option is selected. By default, your "selected value" will be the object in the list that was picked.

Comment: This behavior is documented here. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

you can opt not identify optionsValue, that would set the selected value to the full object and you can do what ever you like ... including having all the properties available (if I got your question right)

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedModel">
    <select data-bind="options: $root.myList,
                       optionsText: 'type',
                       value: nameSomething"></select><br />
        Display this: <span data-bind="text: nameSomething().id"><br />
    Store this: <span data-bind="text: nameSomething().nameId"><br /> <!-- not displaying anything -->
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedModel, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

check out my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bgap47d4/2/

Comment: I see. So by not setting an "optionsValue" it will instead set the selected object to the observable? Please let me know if i got it right.

Answer (score 0):

It's directly not possible. There are at least three possible ways to do it:

1. using a computed (can be a pureComputed) that finds the value by key in the array
2. creating an observable, and subscribe a function to the `nameId` that updates that observable

You can use the [selectedOptions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) binding and subscribe or get the value from the currently selected option in the bound `observableArray`, but it's only another alternative.

This is a solution for your problem, with the structure which you you shpuld use in your viewmodel, using the first option.

```js
var vm2 = (function() {
  
  var list = ko.observableArray(
    [{ id: 1, type: 'foo1'}, 
     { id: 2, type: 'foo2' }, 
     { id: 3, type: 'foo3' }]
  );
  
  var selectedId = ko.observable();
  
  var selectedType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return list().find(function(l) { return l.id == selectedId(); }).type;
  });
  
  return {
    list: list,
    selectedId: selectedId,
    selectedType: selectedType
  };
  
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: list,
                       optionsText: 'type',
                       optionsValue: 'id',
                       value: selectedId"></select><br />
    Display this: <span data-bind="text: selectedType"></span><br />
    Store this: <span data-bind="text: selectedId"></span><br /> <!-- not displaying anything -->
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedModel, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I was also thinking of using the computed/pureComputed, but the list is from the database and I'm not sure how to do it. Think you can show examples for #1 and #2?

Comment: Is it okay for you to provide code examples? for reference

Comment: @BoyPasmo I've included one of the samples. The second sholud be obvious